# Difference between object ownership and Block Public Access feature of AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I see this setting in my `Permissions` tab of an `S3` bucket

[image]

However, I (though I) had explicitly disabled all ACL-related manipulation of the bucket through this:

[image]

What is their difference?

Answer (score 1):

Object Ownership and Block Public Access are two distinct concepts related to managing access control in AWS S3. Here's a breakdown of each concept:

**Object Ownership:**

Object Ownership refers to the ownership of objects stored in an S3 bucket. When an object is created in an S3 bucket, it is owned by the AWS account that created it by default. The object owner has full control over the object and can manage its access permissions. The object owner can grant or revoke permissions for other AWS accounts or IAM users to access the object:

Ownership of an object can be transferred between AWS accounts if the necessary permissions are granted. This can be useful, for example, when moving objects between buckets or accounts for organisational purposes or when sharing objects with other AWS accounts.

**Block Public Access:**

Block Public Access is a feature in S3 that helps prevent accidental public access to objects stored in S3 buckets. When Block Public Access is enabled at the bucket level, it overrides any existing permissions or policies that grant public access to objects in the bucket.
Block Public Access provides four settings to control public access:

**a. BlockPublicAcls:** When enabled, it blocks new Access Control Lists (ACLs) that grant public access.
**b. IgnorePublicAcls:** If enabled, it ignores any public ACLs on objects and blocks access based on bucket policies.
**c. BlockPublicPolicy:** When enabled, it blocks new bucket policies that grant public access.
**d. RestrictPublicBuckets:** If enabled, it blocks public access to the entire bucket and any objects within it.

These settings help enforce a higher level of security by preventing accidental public exposure of S3 objects. It ensures that only authorized users or AWS accounts can access the objects stored in the bucket.

In summary, object ownership is about determining which AWS account owns an object and controls its access permissions, while Block Public Access is a feature that helps prevent accidental public access to S3 objects by overriding existing permissions and policies.

Comment: So despite me disabling ACLs by full enabling `block_public_access` if I need **complete** disabling of ACLs this is something that has to be done in the bucket ownership as well?